# Elasticsearch-Python 2.7-Configure an index for analyzer

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to build an index using the python API, with the following code (In particular I am trying to configure an analyzer):

```
doc = {
"settings": {
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "folding": {
      "tokenizer": "standard",
      "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
      }
     }
   }
  }
}

res = es.indices.create(index='index_db',body=doc)
```

But when I try to feed the database with some example data: 'My œsophagus caused a débâcle' (the same example of the website) I don't obtain : 'my, oesophagus, caused, a, debacle' but again: 'my, œsophagus caused, a, débâcle'. I think the problem is in the creation of the index. Do I use the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempt I found the solution. It was a syntax problem.
The correct answer is:

```
doc = {        
     "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                        "default" : {
                                "tokenizer" : "standard",
                                "filter" : ["standard", "asciifolding"]
                                    }
                             }
                         }
               }
}
es.indices.create(index='forensic_db',body=doc)
```